# How can I reason about big O for various functions?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Consider the following functions:

```
f(n)   = 2^n
g(n)   = n!
h(n)   = n^logn
```

Which of the following statements about the asymptotic behavior of f(n), g(n), and h(n) is true?

```
(A) f(n) = O(g(n)); g(n) = O(h(n))
(B) f(n) = \Omega(g(n)); g(n) = O(h(n))
(C) g(n) = O(f(n)); h(n) = O(f(n))
(D) h(n) = O(f(n)); g(n) = \Omega(f(n))
```

I already know this

> According to order of growth: h(n) < f(n) < g(n)
>
> (g(n) is asymptotically greater than f(n) and f(n) is asymptotically greater than h(n) )

We can easily see above order by taking logs of the given 3 functions

```
lognlogn < n < log(n!)  (logs of the given f(n), g(n) and h(n)).
```

Note that log(n!) =  \theta(nlogn)

But how to figure out the correct option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see from calculus that if

```
lim {n -> inf} a(n) / b(n) < inf
```

then

```
a(n) = O(b(n))
```

Also note that all the functions here go to infinity, so we can use [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Finally, note that, asymptotically, [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) gives

```
lim {n -> inf} n! / (sqrt(2 pi n) (n / e)^n) = 1
```

If you combine these three things you can see that:

```
lim {n -> inf} 2^n / n! = lim {n -> inf} 2^n / (sqrt(2 pi n) (n / e)^n) = 0
```

and

```
lim {n -> inf} n^{log(n)} / 2^n = < inf
```

So D is correct.